# Setting Java heap space for Hadoop job in Eclipse with Maven configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, hadoop2

I have a Hadoop project in Eclipse whose dependencies are handled by Maven. I am currently able to run the Hadoop job inside Eclipse and I do not have Hadoop installed (since Maven gets all the dependencies). The problem is that I am getting the heap space exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know that I could enlarge the Java heap space in the Hadoop configuration, if I would have Hadoop installed. How could I enlarge the Java heap space when running the job from Eclipse if I do not have Hadoop installed? I would like to keep dependency management to Maven, but would need a way to change some Hadoop configuration. Could this be done in Maven configuration file `pom.xml`? If not, can I do in through command line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are executing the Hadoop job as LocalJobRunner from eclipse. If that is the case, Hadoop job uses the same JVM of eclipse. You cannot modify heap memory maven configuration file, instead the heap of eclipse JVM should be increased.

Refer [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) link for increasing the heap of eclipse.

Comment: Just to collaborate on some more of my findings. The problem was indeed in the JVM arguments, however enlarging `-Xmx` for Eclipse itself did not solve the problem. As I figured out with [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net) LocalJobRunner was being run with heap size 256M even if Eclipse was running with 4G of heap space. So to enlarge the heap for LocalJobRunner you have to add `-Xmx512M` into the setting under  `Run -> Run configuration -> Arguments -> VM arguments`.